# How to convert linq expression with join to lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have the following expression:

```
_callPairs = (from req in _requests
                      join resp in _responses
                          on req.RequestId equals resp.RequestId
                          where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.RequestId)
                      select new CallPair(req, resp)).ToList();
```

which I want to change to lambda. I tried:

```
_callPairs = _requests.Where(req => (_responses.Where(res => res.RequestId == 
    req.RequestId)).Where(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.RequestId)).ToList();
```

unfortunately, this does not compile.

Can someone explain to me how I convert a linq expression with a join to a lambda one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [`Join()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
_callPairs = _requests.Where(req => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.RequestId))
                      .Join(_responses, 
                            req => req.RequestId,
                            resp => resp.RequestId,
                            (req, resp) => new CallPair(req, resp)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of join. Here you have an inner join (you can tell by the absence of an `into` clause), so the corresponding extension method syntax is using [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx):

```
_callPairs = _requests
                 .Where(req => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.RequestId))
                 .Join(_responses,                 // join to what?
                       req => req.RequestId,       // compare this from requests
                       resp => resp.RequestId,     // to this key from responses
                       (req, resp) => new CallPair(req, resp)) // create result
                 .ToList();
```

For group joins (`join ... on ... into ...`) you would use [`GroupJoin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin.aspx) instead.